# PasswordDeriveBytes (System.Security.Cryptography) fails if disposed

Tags: c#, .net, security, cryptography, idisposable

The usage of the PasswordDeriveBytes class in a using block (which disposes it, because it implements IDisposable) creates a problem if the class is used a second time. This is the code:

```
public class AES
{
    protected static CryptoData localCryptoData;

    static AES()
    {
        localCryptoData = new CryptoData();
    }

    public static string Encrypt(CryptoData cryptoData)
    {
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes pass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(cryptoData.Password, cryptoData.Salt, "SHA1", 2))
        using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            byte[] keyBytes = pass.GetBytes(cryptoData.KeySize / 8);
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = symmetricKey.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, cryptoData.InitVector))
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(cryptoData.ByteText, 0, cryptoData.ByteText.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    public static string Decrypt(CryptoData cryptoData)
    {
        using (PasswordDeriveBytes pass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(cryptoData.Password, cryptoData.Salt, "SHA1", 2))
        using (RijndaelManaged symmetricKey = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoData.Text);
            byte[] keyBytes = pass.GetBytes(cryptoData.KeySize / 8);
            symmetricKey.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            symmetricKey.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = symmetricKey.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, cryptoData.InitVector))
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(cipherTextBytes))
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                byte[] textBytes = new byte[cipherTextBytes.Length];
                int count = cryptoStream.Read(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length); //throws CryptographicException - Padding is invalid and cannot be removed.
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(textBytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
    }
```

If this class is used in this manner:

AES.Encrypt(cryptoData);
 AES.Decrypt(cryptoData);

Ths first use gives you a correct AES encrypted string, but if fails with an exception when trying to decrypt the same string. The problem lies in the assigning of the first parameter (The password to derive the key from) from the PasswordDeriveBytes class, when this password is given through a Byte array. If it is given as a string (because of the overload) it works ok.

The helper CryptoData class:

```
public class CryptoData
{
    private string text;
    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            text = value;

            if (value != null)
            {
                ByteText = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
            }
            else
            {
                ByteText = null;
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] ByteText { get; private set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }
    public int KeySize { get; set; }
    public byte[] InitVector { get; set; }
    public byte[] Salt { get; set; }
}
```

If you just change this row in the methods:

```
using (PasswordDeriveBytes pass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(cryptoData.Password, 
      cryptoData.Salt, "SHA1", 2))
```

into

```
using (PasswordDeriveBytes pass = new PasswordDeriveBytes("somePassword", 
         cryptoData.Salt, "SHA1", 2))
```

everything works fine. The problem is, the instance of PasswordDeriveBytes does not get the byte array for password the second time used, because of the using statement. If a string has been passed, instead of a byte array, it works.

Edit: After reviewing it closer, it seems that there is a problem in the default property setter for the password parameter. It gets the pointer of the array, and that is why it is disposing it. It should make a value.clone() of the array, as is the case with the salt array.  It's a definite bug.

Am I right, or am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

***Change the first line in AES.Encrypt() and AES.Decrypt methods with this and it works: ***

```
 using (PasswordDeriveBytes pass = new PasswordDeriveBytes(
        (byte[])cryptoData.Password.Clone(), 
        cryptoData.Salt, "SHA1", 2))
```

Comment: You can't use an object after it has been disposed.

Comment: Please read and understand the code. Nobody uses the same object twice. There are different methods.

Comment: Can you post the exception details, including stack-trace?

Comment: "It gets the pointer of the array, and that is why it is disposing it. " - You cannot dispose an array, and it seems very unlikely it would alter anything inside the array.

Comment: @Henk well, dispose is a wrong word for the array, but it actualy clears the array with Array.Clear(), which makes it all zeroes.

Comment: You're right, I could verify this. Weird.

Comment: This happens in the dispose method of the PasswordDeriveBytes, and that is why I said it was disposing it.

Comment: The reason you ran into this problem is you were not using a reference to the `cryptoData` the reason cryptoData.Password.Clone() works is you send a cloned reference to the array.**"It's a definite bug.**" - I agree the bug was in your code.

Comment: @Ramhound - can you expand on that? The holder of the array does not seem to matter here. The issue is that the Password class zeroes one of its params.

Comment: @Ramhou - you're totally off track. When the array contains Value types (bytes) there is no shallow/deep copy. The workaround simply uses a copy of the password array to be used & zeroed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - Its just something I noticed.

Comment: Note that `PasswordDeriveBytes` has many, many things wrong with it. You should use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead. If you use it, use it for max of 20 bytes. You also seem to generate a random IV implicitly, and then forget about it.

Comment: @Ramhound - it's not a bug in my code, it's a bug in the PasswordDeriveBytes class. If it were my bug, then the salt that I use (which is also a byte array) should also be nullified like it is done with the password array. Another thing, an object is by convention passed by value, and a class using an input parameter isn't allowed to change this parameter directly. It can use it, but must not change it. Ergo, the salt array stays unchanged, the password array is changed. <- A Bug.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly counter-intuitive and undocumented behavior, although whether or not it is a bug could possibly be debated. Basically, when you pass the password byte array to the constructor, the PasswordDeriveBytes instance is taking ownership of that array. This is similar to the way StreamReader takes ownership of the Stream which is passed to it, and will Dispose it when it is Disposed (this behavior was also [criticized](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361389/allow-binaryreader-and-streamreader-to-wrap-a-stream-without-disposing-it) on similar grounds, which led to the addition of a boolean parameter to the StreamReader constructor in .NET 4.0 which can prevent the underlying stream from being Disposed).

Cloning the byte array before you pass it in is probably your best option.